# What value should be assigned to k so that h will be continous?

Tags: calculus, functions, graphing-functions

> Consider the function $h(x)$ defined by
> $$ h(x) = \begin{cases} \frac{\tan 5x}{4x} & x \neq 0 \\ k & x = 0 \end{cases} $$
> What value should be assigned to $k$ to assure that $h$ is continuous?

My approach: I tried to find a way to rewrite the function (tan 5x)/ 4x.

1. That can be rewritten as ((sin 5x)/ (cos 5x))/ 4x
2. ((sin 5x)/ (cos 5x)) * 1 / 4x
3. I kept in mind that there is a rule that sin x / x is equal to 1
4. I rewrote the expression to be (sin 5x / x) * (1 / (cos 5x) * 4)
5. 1 * (1 / (4 cos 5x)); There can be no value of the function where x = 0
6. The graph shows that as well: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KgM6t.png
7. At a value between 1.2 and 1.3 lies the value of y which must be defined in ordered to make the function continuous.
8. But I cannot solve this by graphing it- it must be done by hand. So how will I go from step 5 to getting the value of k that will make this function h, continuous?

Comment: Step 3 is wrong; $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ is not “equal to 1.”  I think you mean that $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x} = 1$.  If you change this, you are close to showing that $\lim_{x \to 0} h(x) = \frac{5}{4}$.  What does it mean for $h$ to be continuous at $0$?

Comment: You want the definition with limits in it.

Comment: Step 5 also doesn’t make sense: 1 * (1 / (4 cos 5x))  is perfectly fine at $x=0$.

Answer (score 5):

By the definition of $h(x)$ provided by you, it can be can say that for $h(x)$ to be a continuous function
$$\lim_{x\to 0}h(x)=h(0)$$

That is,   $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\tan(5x)}{4x}=k$$
(with $k\in \Bbb R$) which we can rewrite as, $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\tan(5x)}{5x}\times\frac{5}{4}=k$$
Now since, $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\tan 5x}{5x}=1$$

so, $$\frac{5}{4}=k=1.25.$$
Like you said, $k$ should be between 1.2 and 1.3.
Do take a look at comments highlighting some of your mistakes regarding trigonometric limits.

Comment: I have appreciated also your answer: +1

Comment: @Sebastiano Grazie amico. Thank you for the edit as well.

Comment: I am glad to help you 

Comment: Oh! I understand now, thank you so much for explaining this to me!

Answer (score 3):

Your idea is good but there are many issues as indicated in the comments.

Simply, to assure continuity, by the definition, we need to assume:

$$k=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\tan (5x)}{4x}=\lim_{x\to 0} \left(\frac54\cdot \frac{\sin (5x)}{5x}\cdot\frac{1}{\cos(5x)}\right)=\frac 54$$

in such way that

$$h(0)=\lim_{x\to 0} h(x)$$

Comment: Thank you for clarifying!!